# Akka.net - remember entities issue

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka.net-cluster, akka.net-persistence

Getting the following errors on our Akka.net application, anyone got any idea what causes these

```
"Bet": Failed to load initial entity ids from remember entities store within [00:00:05], 
stopping shard for backoff and restart
```

```
Message [RecoveryTick] from [akka://xxxx/system/sharding/Bet/17/RememberEntitiesStore#346032082]
 to [akka://xxxx/system/sharding/Bet/17/RememberEntitiesStore#346032082] was not delivered. 
[4] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior then 
[akka://xxx/system/sharding/Bet/17/RememberEntitiesStore#346032082] may have terminated unexpectedly. 
This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 
'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'. 
Message content: Akka.Persistence.RecoveryTick
```

Getting these errors in log file

Comment: It looks like your actor is faulting without a supervisor to oversee the actor restart or choose another actor to take over that letter queue. Some code would be helpful.